# Scale HD TV resolution with black around it

Tags: hardware

I'm trying to scale down my tv monitor so it will be like my smaller monitor. Is there a way I can make it smaller and have black around it so it will be the same size as the other one. Essentially I want to have a small screen on a large tv. How can I do that?